# error in subject registration

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm facing a problem here. First off, what I'm doing here is subject registration system for students. I've set a part of code to limit the same student from registering the same subject again and again. But sadly, that has given me a reversed effect. My error is that when a student registered a subject, other students can't register that particular subject even though they have never registered it before. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 <?php

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        exit('Unauthorized access!');
    }

       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $studentid = $_POST['studentid'];
       $program = $_POST['program'];
       $fintake = $_POST['fintake'];
       $courseid = $_POST['courseid'];

       include("include/config.php");

    //this could be the problem,i'm not sure
       $check_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT r_id FROM course_registration WHERE r_cid='$courseid' limit 1");

       if(mysqli_fetch_array($check_query))
       {
          echo 'Error：Course ID:',$courseid,' already exists. <a href="javascript:history.back(-1);">Return</a>';
          exit;
       }

       $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM course_list WHERE c_cid = '$courseid'");

       if(mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {

          $sql = "INSERT INTO course_registration (r_name,r_sid,r_program,r_fintake,r_cid) VALUES('$name','$studentid','$program','$fintake','$courseid')";

          if(mysqli_query($link,$sql))
          {
             exit('Success! Register course successfully. <a href="index.php">Homepage</a>');
          } 
          else 
          {
             echo 'Sorry! Add data failed:',mysqli_error($link),'<br />';
             echo 'Click here <a href="javascript:history.back(-1);">Return</a> retry';
          }
       }
       else
       {
          echo 'Sorry! Wrong course id.','<br />';
          echo 'Click here <a href="javascript:history.back(-1);">Return</a> retry';
       }
    ?>
```

Database: course_registration

```
r_id r_name              r_sid    r_program  r_fintake  r_cid 
1    TAN KOON ENG        0187904  DIP-CS     01-2015    DTP-3033
2    TAN KOON ENG        0187904  DIP-CS     01-2015    DCS-22104
3    CRISTIANO RONALDO   0190007  DIP-GT     09-2016    DGP-2254
4    CRISTIANO RONALDO   0190007  DIP-GT     09-2016    DGA-1224
```

Comment: add where clause studentid=$studenid   too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checking `courseid` is exists in table but need to check `courseid` is exists for particular `student` so you need to add `where clause` like this

```
SELECT r_id FROM course_registration WHERE r_cid='$courseid' AND r_sid='$studentid'"
```

Comment: not working mean which one  ??  but this is a way to find subject and student already exists in table .

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick its useful for future user reference @StevenChen

Answer (score 0):

you can try this add and studentid in where
   $check_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT r_id FROM 
      course_registration WHERE r_cid='$courseid' AND r_sid='$studentid'");

Comment: try (mysqli_num_rows($check_query)>0) in place of mysqli_fetch_array($check_query) i think this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In your given case, you are checking the course id in the database and limiting to 1 only hence, it reports an error in your case. To check whether a student has enrolled into course or not. You must also check the student id with courseid. Maybe, this query might help you:

```
SELECT r_id FROM course_registration WHERE r_sid='$studentid' AND r_cid='$courseid'"
```